# select only complete set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to select only those values that have at least minimum one row from each type.

```
File|Value          |Type  
001 |"Crektolap"    |1  
001 |"123.45"       |2  
001 |"0.00"         |4  
002 |"Cream floure" |1  
002 |"56.89"        |2  
002 |"Supercat"     |3  
002 |"0.01"         |4
```

There are available: `1,2,3,4` types

The result I would want in result, would be:

```
File|Value          |Type  
002 |"Cream floure" |1  
002 |"56.89"        |2  
002 |"Supercat"     |3  
002 |"0.01"         |4
```

Is this even posible in one query?

Comment: so you don't want File #001, because it's lacking type #3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with window functions:

```
select file, value, type
from (select t.*, max(dr) over (partition by file) as numtypes
      from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (partition by file order by type) as dr
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
where numtypes = 4;
```

`dense_rank()` counts the number of different values of `type`, enumerated on each row.  The `max()` then gets the maximum value, and the outer query selects rows where there are four types.

If you don't know the number of types:

```
select file, value, type
from (select t.*, max(dr) over (partition by file) as numtypes
      from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (partition by file order by type) as dr
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
where numtypes = (select count(distinct type) from table t);
```